# Copy image from Uri in another Folder with another name in Kotlin Android

Tags: android, kotlin, copy, uri

i am working on an App right now and i want to safe a picture from which i have the uri in another dictonary with a new name.
My App is crashing right now, after i press the button.

The Copy Code function is from Stackoverflow as well, i dont understand it completly, but i am pretty sure, that i used it right. But i'm not sure, if i do the sourcePath and destinationPath right. Also sry for my bad english, i hopy my stuff is understandable.

This is my code rightnow, maybe you can help me:

```
package com.example.stepbook

import android.content.Intent
import android.net.Uri
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.widget.Button
import android.widget.EditText
import android.widget.ImageView
import android.widget.Toast

import androidx.core.net.toUri

import java.io.File
import java.io.FileInputStream
import java.io.FileOutputStream
import java.net.URI
import java.nio.channels.FileChannel

import java.util.*

class ChooseWeight : AppCompatActivity() {





    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_choose_weight)

        val uri : Uri? = intent.getStringExtra("Foto")?.toUri()

        val imageView : ImageView = findViewById(R.id.progress_Picture)

        imageView.setImageURI(uri)

        val button : Button = findViewById(R.id.accept_photo_button)

        val kiloText : EditText = findViewById(R.id.weight_input)


        button.setOnClickListener {
            if(kiloText.text.toString().toIntOrNull() == null){
                val toastNull = Toast.makeText(this, "Bitte gib ein Gewicht an!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                toastNull.show()
            }else{

                val kilo : Int = kiloText.text.toString().toInt()
                val toast = Toast.makeText(this, "Bitte gib ein realistisches Gewicht an! ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                if(kilo <= 45 || kilo >= 250){
                    toast.show()
                }else{

                    val sourcePath : File = File(URI(uri.toString()))
                    val destinationPath: File = File(URI("content://media/external/images/media/stepbookgallery/" + Calendar.getInstance().toString() + kilo.toString()))
                    copyPicture(sourcePath, destinationPath )





                    val intent = Intent(this, MainActivity::class.java)
                    startActivity(intent)
                }
            }



        }




    }

    fun copyPicture(sourcePath : File, destinationPath : File){
        if(!sourcePath.exists()){
            return
        }

        var source : FileChannel? = null;
        var destination : FileChannel? = null;

        source = FileInputStream(sourcePath).channel
        destination = FileOutputStream(destinationPath).channel

        if(destination != null && source != null){
            destination.transferFrom(source, 0, source.size())
        }
        if(source != null){
            source.close()
        }
        if(destination != null){
            destination.close()
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: You cannot use the File class for content scheme uries. Further you did not tell the value of the uri that your activity got from intent.

Comment: `URI("content://media/external/images/media/stepbookgallery/" + Calendar.getInstance().toString() + kilo.toString())` You can not build up a MediaStore uri yourself in such a way.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 types of uri -> content uri and file uri:

Content uri : *"content://media/external/audio/media/710"*

Base URI : *"file:///sdcard/media/audio/ringtones/nevergonnagiveyouup.mp3"*

File class needs file uri. Because content uri does not have a scheme. The function below creates a temporary file using content uri with inputStream. InputStream reads the file from content uri, creates a new file with it. And you can extract file uri, file path from this file. For your problem, you can edit outputDir and fileName variables to save your new file.

```
fun createFileFromContentUri(fileUri : Uri) : File{

var fileName : String = ""

fileUri.let { returnUri ->
    requireActivity().contentResolver.query(returnUri,null,null,null)
}?.use { cursor ->
    val nameIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(OpenableColumns.DISPLAY_NAME)
    cursor.moveToFirst()
    fileName = cursor.getString(nameIndex)
}

//  For extract file mimeType
val fileType: String? = fileUri.let { returnUri ->
    requireActivity().contentResolver.getType(returnUri)
}

val iStream : InputStream = 
requireActivity().contentResolver.openInputStream(fileUri)!!
val outputDir : File = context?.cacheDir!!
val outputFile : File = File(outputDir,fileName)
copyStreamToFile(iStream, outputFile)
iStream.close()
return  outputFile
}

fun copyStreamToFile(inputStream: InputStream, outputFile: File) {
inputStream.use { input ->
    val outputStream = FileOutputStream(outputFile)
    outputStream.use { output ->
        val buffer = ByteArray(4 * 1024) // buffer size
        while (true) {
            val byteCount = input.read(buffer)
            if (byteCount < 0) break
            output.write(buffer, 0, byteCount)
        }
        output.flush()
    }
}
}
```

Also, check this [link](https://commonsware.com/blog/2016/03/16/how-publish-files-via-content-uri.html) for the answer to "How to Publish Files Via a content Uri?" question.